# An unexpected error, please what should i do?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, generics, frontend, react-icons

Failed to compile.

Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'react-icons/fa' in 'C:\Users\Damola Gbenga\Documents\chat-app\src\components'
ERROR in ./src/components/Sidebar.jsx 7:0-44
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'react-icons/fa' in 'C:\Users\Damola Gbenga\Documents\chat-app\src\components'

ERROR in ./src/components/Sidebar.jsx 8:0-47
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'react-icons/bi' in 'C:\Users\Damola Gbenga\Documents\chat-app\src\components'

ERROR in ./src/components/Sidebar.jsx 9:0-40
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'react-icons/hi' in 'C:\Users\Damola Gbenga\Documents\chat-app\src\components'

ERROR in ./src/components/Sidebar.jsx 10:0-42
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'react-icons/bs' in 'C:\Users\Damola Gbenga\Documents\chat-app\src\components'

webpack compiled with 4 errors

Comment: looks like you're trying to import modules you haven't installed - lines 7-10 in your `components/Sidebar.jsx` file

Comment: Look at what the messages are saying. "Module not found". What do you think that means given your code structure, and what you've installed? How do _you_ think you can resolve the problem?